# Can you have more than one python in terminal?

Tags: python, django

I'm a bit confused with what is happening to run my django apps. When I use the command `python manage.py runserver` I don't get the appropriate response from the server. However, when I use `python2.6 manage.py runserver` the server actually runs.

Can someone help me with this confusion and also suggest to me how I can simplify this problem? Ideally I don't want different versions of python and only want to be able to type `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: Seems as if you have two pythons installed.  Try `python -V` to see what version `python` is.

Comment: it says "Python 2.6.1". However, do you have a suggestion to solve the problem above? I'd like to only be able to type one thing to run django.

Comment: More details needed.  I'd expect python2.6 to run python 2.6.1 unless you have a new version of 2.6.  So, confirm there are two versions installed.  If there are, either decide to live with using `python2.6` or set your path so that the one which works is in the path - this is OS dependent.  Alas I'm about to leave the keyboard for a while, so can't provide more help anytime soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  It is fairly common.  You can find out the location of an executable with `which`, and resolve symlinks with `ls`.

```
$ ls -l `which python`
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Jul 13 18:50 /usr/bin/python -> python2.6
$ ls -l `which python3`
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Jul 27 22:24 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.1
```

On Debian and some other systems, you may need to resolve multiple symlinks.

```
$ ls -l `which nc`
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Oct  7 15:16 /bin/nc -> /etc/alternatives/nc
$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/nc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Oct  7 15:16 /etc/alternatives/nc -> /bin/nc.openbsd
```

If you want to only type `python` and get the version you want, make an alias.  Add a line to your `.bashrc` file (or wherever you keep such lines):

```
alias python=python2.6
```

Note that this will not affect scripts: if you run "python" in a script, it will get the old version, not an alias.  Aliases are only for interactive use.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can have multiple versions of Python sitting side-by-side on your computer.

It sounds like `python` on your host is symbolically linked to a version other than `python2.6`. You can find out this version by running:

```
python --version
```

...or...

```
python -V
```

...if that does not work.

Setting the default Python version depends on how you installed Python in the first place.

For Mac OS X, see [How can I change the default Python version on Snow Leopard?](https://superuser.com/questions/35256/how-can-i-change-the-default-python-version-on-snow-leopard)

Comment: Do you have a suggestion on how I can just get one python version to run django?

Comment: `python --version` doesn't work on some older pythons, which is why I suggested the `-V` flag in my comment on the question.

Comment: @cfarm54: See http://superuser.com/questions/35256/how-can-i-change-the-default-python-version-on-snow-leopard

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to have two versions of python.  The easiest way I've found to make `python` execute `python2.6` (without breaking the other version for anyone else) is by using an alias.  To do this, simply edit the following and add it to your `~/.profile` file:

```
alias python=/path/to/your/python2.6
```

Log out and back in, and when you run `python` it should execute the correct binary.  If you wish to revert back, simply delete this line from your `~/.profile`.